# Tableview cell selection problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hello I am using grouped table view and selecting Tableview's cell with blueselection style.

But when is select cell and go to next view and again come back to previous view the cell is still selected and if i choose another cell 2cells are showing selected.

see the image and below in my code:

[image]

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    JobViewTableCell *cell = (JobViewTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"iPadJobViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = self.JobViewcell;
        }
        else {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"JobViewTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.JobViewcell;

        }
    }


    [cell setJobID:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[(Jobs *)[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]JobId]]];
    [cell setJobTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(Jobs *)[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]Title]]];

    NSString *newDate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(Jobs *)[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]Date]];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *myDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:newDate];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    NSString *str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];

    NSLog(@"%@",str);



    [cell setJobDate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str]];
    [cell setLocation:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(Jobs *)[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]Location]]];
    [dateFormat release];
    return cell;
}
```

please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your tableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, add `deselectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
    . . .
}
```